# How do I correctly load user_profile_form() to use in my theme?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am trying to theme the user profile edit page using user_profile_form() and need help how to achieve this. In my template.php I have the following code:

```
function marinelli_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks['user_profile_form'] = array(
    // Forms always take the form argument.
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','marinelli'),
    'template' => 'templates/user-profile-edit',
  );
}

function marinelli_preprocess_user_profile_form(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $form_id = 'user_profile_form';
  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($user);

  // Load user.pages.inc and ensure it is automatically reloaded if
  // this form is rebuilt via AJAX or other means.
  form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');

  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_build_form($form_id, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need to follow:-

```
function THENAME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

return array(
    'edit_profile_user_profile_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'templates/edit/user-profile',
        'render element' => 'form',
        ),
);
}
```

Next thing You need to create a file called user-profile.tpl.php and save it in template folder.

In the user-profile.tpl.php file, write the following code to print out the fields:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_NAME_OF_FIELD']); ?>
```